# How can I check if an integers value is 0 or because it is null,it is taking its value as 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer

I have an integer(int a) whose value can be ranged between -30 to +30.so if the user selects a value from the range provided,(int a) value should change accordingly.but then sometimes,when the user does not select anything from the provided range and skips the option,(int a)is been set to null and automatically assigning the value by itself as 0.how can I differentiate this and and the user himself choosing 0 as the value of (int a) as it is also included in the provided range.

Comment: It would be helpful for us to see the relevant part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the initial value of the integer into something that is clearly outside the range (-999, for example). So that when you re-check the integer, if the value is out of the range's bounds then you know the value has never been set.

Alternatively you could encapsulate the value in an object instead of using the primitive, i.e you could use NSNumber.